# How does the font size work in sprite fonts in C# XNA?

Tags: c#, text, fonts, xna, rendering

How does the font size work in sprite fonts in C# XNA? For example maybe font size 10 is drawn from the top to bottom of a lowercase charecter by default 10 pixels tall when output with SpriteBatch's drawString. I've noted that some charecters are much wider or taller than most, extending a considrable distance downwards or to the right of a normal charecter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it depends on the font. You can use [`SpriteFont.MeasureString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb464128.aspx) to determine the rendered dimensions of text.